# When does $f(g(x)) \neq g(f(x))$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Need to show that there exists bijective functions $ f: X \to X $ and $g: X \to X $ such that $f(g(x)) \neq g(f(x). $ 
where $ X $ is a set with $ \ge 3  $ elements.

How do I show this?

Comment: Let $X=\{ a,b,c \}$. Try some functions, there are only a few.

Comment: As an aside, it is *usually* the case that $f(g(x))\neq g(f(x))$.  By trying more than one example you should have found such an example simply by guess and check with almost no effort.

Comment: To answer the question in the title: Most of the time.

Comment: Almost every example you could think of works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:**

$(x+1)^3\neq x^3+1$

$~~~~~$

Answer (score 2):

*Hint:* Think of $X=\{1,2,3\}$ as a triangle with vertexes $1$, $2$ and $3$. Then let $f$ and $g$ be permutations, which for example change the order of the vertexes or interchange vertexes. A picture will make things quite easy.

Answer (score 1):

One function takes $1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8$ respectively to $2,3,4,5,6,7,8,1$, and another takes them to $8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1.$
$$
\begin{array}{cccccc}
1 & \mapsto & 2 & \mapsto & 7 \\
2 & \mapsto & 3 & \mapsto & 6 \\
3 & \mapsto & 4 & \mapsto & 5 \\
4 & \mapsto & 5 & \mapsto & 4 \\
5 & \mapsto & 6 & \mapsto & 3 \\
6 & \mapsto & 7 & \mapsto & 2 \\
7 & \mapsto & 8 & \mapsto & 1 \\
8 & \mapsto & 1 & \mapsto & 8 \\ \\ \hline \\
1 & \mapsto & 8 & \mapsto & 1 \\
2 & \mapsto & 7 & \mapsto & 8 \\
3 & \mapsto & 6 & \mapsto & 7 \\
4 & \mapsto & 5 & \mapsto & 6 \\
5 & \mapsto & 4 & \mapsto & 5 \\
6 & \mapsto & 3 & \mapsto & 4 \\
7 & \mapsto & 2 & \mapsto & 3 \\
8 & \mapsto & 1 & \mapsto & 2
\end{array}
$$

Answer (score 0):

Take a bijection $f$ on $X$.
 Form a new bijection $g$ by swapping the second coordinates of two elements of $f$. Then $f,g$ are an example.

Proof:

Let $X$ be a set with $\kappa \ge 3$ elements. 
Say $x,y,z$ are some elements of $X$.
Let $f$ be any bijection on $X$ with $(x,y) \in f$, $(y,z) \in f$. 
Later, let $g$ be a bijection with $g = f$ except $(x,z) \in g,  (y,y) \in g$. 
Then $g(f(x)) = g(y) = y$ and $f(g(x)) = f(z) = g(z) \ne y$. 
If $g(z) = y$, then $g$ is not one-to-one- a contradiction to $g$ being a bijection.